# Botões gerados por foreach só executam ajax na ordem que são exibidos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá!
Estou usando um ajax em um botão para que quando clico nele este submeta um form, o botão então muda de VALIDAR para VALIDADO, tudo isso sem recarregar a página.

Eis o código:

```
$('#validar_form').submit(function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'valida_horaextrarh.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'html',
  data: $('#validar_form').serialize(),
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#principal').html(response);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
 });
});
```

O problema é que o código atual só permite que eu clique nos botões na ordem que são exibidos, imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso eu tente validar a solicitação da Pessoa 3, eu preciso validar primeiro a Pessoa 2, pois caso contrário o botão não executa o ajax.

Como resolver isso para que eu possa clicar nos botões em qualquer ordem?

Comment: Cada linha dessa está dentro de um form ?

Comment: Tem um select coletando as linhas no banco, um foreach que tabela elas pra mim enquanto houver dados, cada linha gera esse botão que submete um form pra dar update na linha dizendo que ela foi conferida, o submeter desse form usa o ajax pra não atualizar a página e processar os dados.

Comment: Pergunto o mesmo que o @LeandroLima... cada linha tem um form próprio ou todo o bloco está dentro de um form? Coloque o código que seja possível de executar/testar senão vai ser difícil ajudar.

Comment: Cada linha tem um form, inclusive entendi o porque da pergunta, como ele procura pelo ID do form o problema deve ser esse, o ajax para no primeiro ID que encontra, mas como resolver não sei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código abaixo não é a melhor forma de fazer isso acredito eu. Mas eu não sei qual seria a forma mais elegante de fazer.

Cria os `forms` com o `foreach`:

```
<?php foreach ($linhas as $linha): ?>
    //Cria o form aqui. Observe o ID.
    <form id="#validar_form<?=$linha['id']?>">
        <button onclick=ajax(<?=$linha['id']?>)>Validar</button>
    </form>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Observe que eu concatenei uma chave única que tá vindo do banco dentro do `id` do html. E adicionei uma função chamada `ajax` dentro do botão.

Faz a requisição via `ajax`:

```
function ajax(id) {
$.ajax({
        url: 'valida_horaextrarh.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',
        data: $('#validar_form'+id).serialize(),
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $('#principal').html(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Observe que a informação que é serializada pelo ajax é um `form` com `id` único agora.

Comment: Se é ou não a forma mais elegante não sei, MAS FUNCIONA! Muito obrigado!